# using serverless for large scale cloud database

Tags: azure, aws-lambda, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, serverless-framework

What guidelines have been useful for folks who are looking to have a very large (100TB - PB) cloud database with multiple readers/writers (IoT) sources?

We expect to have a REDIS cache backed by either DynamoDB, Azure CosmosDB, or other (Not yet decided).

But is it a problem to have purely lambda and serverless to service the read/write requests? There are some guidelines from AWS about this:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/how-to-design-your-serverless-apps-for-massive-scale/
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/best-practices-for-organizing-larger-serverless-applications/

and one case study:

- https://www.serverless.com/blog/how-droplr-scales-to-millions-serverless-framework

Comment: Will the IoT sources lead to some form of "fused" data, i.e. if the data is coming from many locations (devices) into a single repository, will the data be fused together into a single, query-able asset, or do you simply need to persist the data from each IoT sensor into a federated repository. Objectivity/DB can run as a distributed database, giving you a single logical view over all of the data in a federated and distributed database. www.objectivity.com dhall@objectivity.com

Comment: Data fusing and conflating

Comment: https://objectivity.com/solutions/use-cases/#IIoT

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for information like this is [Azure Architecture Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/) that has articles on best practices and architectural guidance.

Regarding using Dynamo or Cosmos DB to back Redis, I can't offer any guidance on the efficacy for doing such a thing. What I can say is that I do see customers opt-out of using Redis altogether and use Dynamo or Cosmos as a key/value cache-layer because the latency is good enough.